# What is label address?

Tags: nasm

I can't find in the documentation the exactly implementation of label(not in modern assemblies) To where does it points? I had in my mind that's the address of first instruction,for example:

```
global _start
section .text
_start:
    call exit
exit:
    mov eax,1
    mov ebx,20
    int 0x80

section .data
list:
    dd exit
```

the `list` shouldn't be same address as `exit` that's the first seen by label?
I want to do something like this:

```
mov eax,list
call eax
```

it's a try to make function-pointer-like in assembly.

Comment: the label is just a mnemonic referring to the address of the first instruction AFTER the lable. e.g. `exit:` points to wherever the `mov eax,1` physically exists in ram.

Comment: `mov eax,list\nmov ebx,exit` why isn't `eax` and `ebx` same address?

Comment: because list points to a section of memory where you've stored the address of the exit function. e.g. it's not pointing at the actual exit function, it's pointing at where you've stored a pointer to exit.

Comment: Thanks. now I understood. It's possible to get `exit` address from `list` by some align?

Comment: been a while since I did any x86 assembler, but wouldn't `[list]` act as a pointer, so instead of "where list is", it be "using the address stored where list is".

Comment: Works fine. Thanks. But it will make another question,my function-pointer implementation will fail. If a have more than one element in `list`: `invalid combination of opcode and operands`

Comment: forget the above comment; maybe should be a new question,thanks very much.

Comment: @MarcB: Port you comment to ans and then I will mark as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The label is just a mnemonic referring to the address of the first instruction AFTER the label. e.g. `exit:` points to wherever the `mov eax,1` physically exists in ram.